# Losing number when updating table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I'm updating a table by defining a cursor that groups all the duplicated rows together and enumerates the rows (counting from the second one) for each one of these groups:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c1
    IS
        SELECT ROWID,
               DENSE_RANK () OVER (ORDER BY column1, column2) group_num,
               column1,
               column2,
               ROW_NUMBER ()
                   OVER (PARTITION BY column1, column2 ORDER BY ROWID)
                   seq_num,
               LEAD (ROWID)
                   OVER (PARTITION BY column1, column2 ORDER BY ROWID)
                   next_rowid
          FROM table
         WHERE (column1, column2) IN (  SELECT column1, column2
                                          FROM table
                                      GROUP BY column1, column2
                                        HAVING COUNT (*) > 1);
BEGIN
    FOR reg IN c1
    LOOP
        UPDATE table
           SET column1 = column1 || '.' || LPAD (reg.seq_num, 5, '0')
         WHERE ROWID = reg.next_rowid;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

When I have eg. 20 rows that are duplicated according to the criteria `column1, column2` all the rows are properly updated with exception for the ones where `seq_num` **ends in 0**. So, for this case, I would have as a result:

```
column1.00001, column1.00002, column1.00003, column1.00004, column1.00005, column1.00006, column1.00007, column1.00008, column1.00009, column1.0001, column1.00011, column1.00012, column1.00013, column1.00014, column1.00015, column1.00016, column1.00017, column1.00018, column1.00019, column1.0002
```

Anyone has an idea why is this happening?

Comment: WHY do you use a cursor? The same update can be accomplished in plain SQL without using a cursor.

Comment: My guess is that column1 is really a NUMBER column and so inserting e.g. '123.00010' results in 123.0001 being stored.

Comment: @wildplasser how? using the same SELECT statement inside the UPDATE?

Comment: @TonyAndrews that's it. How could I force the numbers that end in 0 to end in 0?

Comment: Yes. Does not Oracle allow that? (I thought they had some kind of row-versioning (snapshot too old ...))

Comment: You can't - a number is just a number, it doesn't have a format.  When **selecting** it you can format it: `select to_char(column1,'99999.99999') from table`.

Comment: @wildplasser I don't see how I could do it without a cursor.. What's the problem with using a cursor?

Comment: ... if you want it **stored** as `123.00010` then you need a VARCHAR2 column not a NUMBER column.

Comment: @TonyAndrews no way to store it as a NUMBER? something like `SET column1 = TO_NUMBER((TO_CHAR(column1 || '.' || LPAD (reg.seq_num, 5, '0')), '99999.99999'))`

Comment: Nope.  NUMBERS are not stored as strings, they are stored as bytes representing the numeric value in scientific notation - see http://www.ixora.com.au/notes/number_representation.htm for details.